# Spring JDBCtemplate ROW Mapper is too slow for a little records

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring, postgresql and trying to run a query by JDBCtemplate ROW Mapper.
I Have around 1 million records in my db and from the query returned only **12 records**.
When I'm running this query on the db its taking **less than a second** but when I'm using `JdbcTemplate` with a `RowMapper` its taking around **11 seconds** to get the result

Here is my code:

**the controller**

```
@RequestMapping(
      path = arrayOf("/getAppData/{userId}", "/getAppData/{userId}/"),
      method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
open fun getAppData(@PathVariable("userId")userId:Long): ResponseEntity<*> {
    var user= userRepo.findOne(userId)?: throw exception(ExceptionEvent.UserIdNotFound,userId)
var groups= groupService.loadListOfNodeIds(user.groupId)
var res= appService.getLineChartByGroupYear(userId,groups)
return ResponseEntity(res, HttpStatus.OK)

}
```

**Service**

```
@Service("appService")
@Transactional
open class AppServiceImpl : BaseService(), AppService {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jdbc: JdbcTemplate

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var complianceRepo: ComplianceRepo

    @Autowired
    open lateinit var groupService: GroupService


//**The query**


    override fun getLineChartByGroupYear(userId: Long,groups: List<Long>): List<Map<LocalDateTime,Float>>? {

        var sql= """ SELECT
                 date,
                  CASE WHEN TOTAL = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1.0 * compliant / total end as compliance_rate
                   from
                   (select
                    date_trunc('month',location_timestamp) as date,
                    count(case when event_type = 'COMPL_HANDWASH' then 1 else null end) as compliant,
                    count(1) as total
                    from compliance
                    where group_id = any(ARRAY $groups) and location_timestamp between (now() - interval '1 year') and now()
                     group by 1) A
                     ORDER BY date; """
        var stopwatch=StopWatch()
        stopwatch.start()

        var res=jdbc.query( sql,
            BeanPropertyRowMapper<lineChartDTO>(lineChartDTO::class.java))
          stopwatch.stop()
          logger.info("LineChartByGroupYear query BeanPropertyRowMapper1: ${stopwatch.totalTimeSeconds}")
        return res

     }
}
```

**the lineChartDto Object** for the row mapper

```
public class lineChartDTO {
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private Float complianceRate;

    public lineChartDTO( LocalDateTime date, Float complianceRate) {
        this.date = date;
        this.complianceRate = complianceRate;
    }

    public lineChartDTO() {
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Float getComplianceRate() {
        return complianceRate;
    }

    public void setComplianceRate(Float complianceRate) {
        this.complianceRate = complianceRate;
    }
 }
```

**the Configuration **

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableJpaRepositories("com.nex")
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 open class DataSourceConfig {


   val DATA_PACKAGE = "com.nex.data"
   val INTERCEPTOR_KEY = "hibernate.ejb.interceptor"


     @Value("\${spring.datasource.username:${Const.NONE}}")
     lateinit var username: String

     @Value("\${spring.datasource.password:${Const.NONE}}")
     lateinit var password: String

  @Value("\${spring.datasource.url}")
  lateinit var url: String

  @Value("\${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
  lateinit var driverClass: String

  @Value("\${spring.datasource.sslenabled}")
   var sslEnabled: Boolean = false

    @Bean
    @Primary
    open fun dataSource(): DataSource {
    var dbUrl = url
    val builder = DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(driverClass)
     if (sslEnabled) {
    val sslPath = ClassPathResource("root.crt").uri.path
    val sslParams = "ssl=true&sslcert=$sslPath&sslrootcert=$sslPath&sslmode=verify-full"
    dbUrl = "$url?$sslParams"
    }
 if (username != Const.NONE && password != Const.NONE) builder.username(username).password(password)
return builder.url(dbUrl).build()
}

 @Bean
 open fun entityManagerFactory(
  factory: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder, dataSource: DataSource,
  properties: JpaProperties): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
  val jpaProperties = HashMap<String, Any>()
  jpaProperties.putAll(properties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource))
  jpaProperties.put(INTERCEPTOR_KEY, hibernateInterceptor())
  return factory.dataSource(dataSource).packages(DATA_PACKAGE)
    .properties(jpaProperties as MutableMap<String, *>)
    .build()
   }

  @Bean
  open fun hibernateInterceptor(): HibernateStatisticsInterceptor {
      return HibernateStatisticsInterceptor()
  }

  @Bean
  open fun requestStatisticsInterceptor(): RequestStatisticsInterceptor {
      return RequestStatisticsInterceptor()
  }
}
```

From the query only 12 records returned every time.
I already tried setting the `fetchSize` but nothing happened.

Comment: Why would you set the fetch size? You're fetching 12 records.

Comment: @Kayaman I deleted that I only tried a solution that i saw before to see if something happen but nothing change

Comment: You are also comparing apples and oranges... Executing a query from your SQL tool and doing that with `JdbcTemplate` are quite different beasts... The first doesn't do object creation and field mapping, you don't need to get a connection and start a transaction etc. etc. You also don't show the JDBC configuration (I suspect you are using a `DriverManagerDataSource` instead of a proper connection pool).

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry,I'm new here, but do you want me to upload more code? a specific one? btw I'm not using DriverManagerDataSource

Comment: Next to that your `@Async` is pretty useless and even if it would you are blocking the call so what is the use of your async call here as you are still blocking and waiting for the result... It is also not clear what you are timing the full request? Only the query and conversion? Nonetheless you are still comparing apples and oranges. Add your configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you saying that the Async is not neseccery here?
All i want is to run this query and wrapped it with the object I made, not anything else, when i timed the query i start from the beginning of the query until it finish to use the jdbc template all this issue took 11 seconds for 12 records. i didn't do something special here, Ill upload my configuration

Comment: Still not clear what you timed, where did you time it only that method, the controller... what where. Why do you want to use the async? It doesn't add anything here but complexity, you try to make it async and the next thing you do is wait for the result making it blocking again. You don't gain any performance or throughput so why add that layer of complexity. Also you still haven't added any database configuration.

Comment: let me make it more clear for you you will see exactly where i timed it

Comment: @M.Deinum Hope that now its more clear. I deleted the Thread stuff bc it is not impact on the time. You can see now in the function where i started to time. this function took 11 seconds

Comment: someone has other solution?

Comment: As stated you are comparing apples and oranges. For starters disable debug logging if you have that enabled. Also instead of the `BeanPropertyRowMapper` try your own custom row mapper and see if that helps.

Comment: @M.Deinum How can i create my own row mapper?
thank you